# How to pivot Dataframe to get count and sum in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I am working with the following structure of Data in R.

Dataframe<-

```
Cust_Id    DateTime             Price    Size     Type    Batch     PI1    PI2    Status
TYY-132    2020-08-01 12:14:15  1500     35       RX1     Nov       08     12     Done
TYY-231    2020-08-01 11:04:45  1000     55       Nav     Dpc       15     12     WIP
TYY-131    2020-08-02 10:18:25  1000     25       Nov     Dpc       12     12     Done
TYY-232    2020-08-02 12:14:34  1200     45       RX1     Nvv       04     04     Done
TYY-112    2020-08-03 06:05:01  1300     54       RX1     Nov       01     04     Open
TYY-442    2020-08-03 20:40:50  1500     15       RTR     Nov       10     12     Done
TYY-432    2020-08-03 17:13:12  1000     48       REE     Nvv       10     15     Done
TYY-235    2020-08-04 15:19:11  500      51       RX1     Nov       10     17     Done
```

I want to pivot the above-mentioned dataframe group by `Date` for a particular category.

Category-1: Where, `Size` is >=35 and <=55 with `Type` = RX1 and `Batch` = Nov and value of either `PI1` or `PI1` must be >=12

Where

- `Count_Order` is the total number of `Cust_Id` for that particular `Date`.
- `Count_Done` is where `Status` is equal to `Done`
- `Total_%` is `Count_Done` divided by `Count_Order`
- `Count_Category1` is those `Cust_Id` for that paricular date which met `Category-1` conditions as mentioned above.
- `Count_Done_Category1` is those `Cust_Id` for that paricular date which met `Category-1` conditions as mentioned above along with `Status` is equal to `Done`.
- `%Category1` is `Count_Done_Category1` divided by `Count_Category1`.

Required Output:

```
Date         Count_Order   Count_Done    Total_%   Count_Category1   Count_Done_Category1  %Category1
2020-08-04   1             1             100.00%   1                 1                     100.00%
2020-08-03   3             2             66.66%    0                 0                     0.00%
2020-08-02   2             2             100.00%   0                 0                     0.00%
2020-08-01   2             1             50.00%    1                 1                     100.00%
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reprodusible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

### [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)

I'm using `magrittr`'s `%>%` here solely for demonstration of flow, not because it's required.

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)   # %>%

out <- dat %>%
  .[, Date := as.Date(round(DateTime - 86400/2, "days")), ] %>%
  .[, Cat1 := between(Size, 35, 55) & Type == "RX1" & Batch == "Nov" &
        (PI1 >= 12 | PI2 >= 12) ] %>%
  .[, .(
    Count_Order          = length(unique(Cust_Id)),
    Count_Done           = sum(Status == "Done"),
    Count_Category1      = sum(Cat1),
    Count_Done_Category1 = sum(Cat1 & Status == "Done")
  ), by = .(Date) ] %>%
  .[, c("Total_%", "%Category1") := .(
    pmax(0, 100 * Count_Done / Count_Order, na.rm = TRUE),
    pmax(0, 100 * Count_Done_Category1 / Count_Category1, na.rm = TRUE)
  )]

out
#          Date Count_Order Count_Done Count_Category1 Count_Done_Category1   Total_% %Category1
#        <Date>       <int>      <int>           <int>                <int>     <num>      <num>
# 1: 2020-08-01           2          1               1                    1  50.00000        100
# 2: 2020-08-02           2          2               0                    0 100.00000          0
# 3: 2020-08-03           3          2               0                    0  66.66667          0
# 4: 2020-08-04           1          1               1                    1 100.00000        100
```

### [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) ([tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse))

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(
    Date = as.Date(round(DateTime - 86400/2, "days")),
    Cat1 = between(Size, 35, 55) & Type == "RX1" & Batch == "Nov" &
             (PI1 >= 12 | PI2 >= 12)
  ) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarize(
    Count_Order          = length(unique(Cust_Id)),
    Count_Done           = sum(Status == "Done"),
    Count_Category1      = sum(Cat1),
    Count_Done_Category1 = sum(Cat1 & Status == "Done")
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
   `Total_%` = pmax(0, 100 * Count_Done / Count_Order, na.rm = TRUE),
    `%Category1` = pmax(0, 100 * Count_Done_Category1 / Count_Category1, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
```

### Base [r](/questions/tagged/r) [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe)

```r
dat <- within(dat, {
  Date = as.Date(round(DateTime - 86400/2, "days"))
  Cat1 = between(Size, 35, 55) & Type == "RX1" & Batch == "Nov" & (PI1 >= 12 | PI2 >= 12)
})
dat2 <- do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat$Date, FUN = function(z) with(z, data.frame(
    Count_Order          = length(unique(Cust_Id)),
    Count_Done           = sum(Status == "Done"),
    Count_Category1      = sum(Cat1),
    Count_Done_Category1 = sum(Cat1 & Status == "Done")
))))
dat2 <- within(dat2, {
    `Total_%` = pmax(0, 100 * Count_Done / Count_Order, na.rm = TRUE)
    `%Category1` = pmax(0, 100 * Count_Done_Category1 / Count_Category1, na.rm = TRUE)
})
```

---

Data

```r
library(data.table)
dat <- fread(text="Cust_Id    DateTime             Price    Size     Type    Batch     PI1    PI2    Status
TYY-132    2020-08-01_12:14:15  1500     35       RX1     Nov       08     12     Done
TYY-231    2020-08-01_11:04:45  1000     55       Nav     Dpc       15     12     WIP
TYY-131    2020-08-02_10:18:25  1000     25       Nov     Dpc       12     12     Done
TYY-232    2020-08-02_12:14:34  1200     45       RX1     Nvv       04     04     Done
TYY-112    2020-08-03_06:05:01  1300     54       RX1     Nov       01     04     Open
TYY-442    2020-08-03_20:40:50  1500     15       RTR     Nov       10     12     Done
TYY-432    2020-08-03_17:13:12  1000     48       REE     Nvv       10     15     Done
TYY-235    2020-08-04_15:19:11  500      51       RX1     Nov       10     17     Done")
dat[, DateTime := as.POSIXct(gsub("_", " ", DateTime))]
```

Comment: Nice and clean solution! Upvoted!

Comment: @r2evans: Getting error `Error in `[.data.frame`(., , `:=`(Date, as.Date(round(Date - 86400/2,  : 
  could not find function ":="`

Comment: You tagged [tag:data.table], so I gave you an answer for the `data.table` package. It's even listed explicitly in the code block that provides sample data.

Comment: This brings into doubt your use of tags on this question. Do you know anything about either of the [tag:dplyr] or [tag:tidyverse] tags?